# After switching to Python 3.6.5_1, the displayed version is still 3.7.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal, homebrew

I am trying to use Python 3.6.5_1 for OpenCV, so I have switched Python versions using "brew switch python 3.6.5_1", but after checking my current version of Python using "python --version", I apparently am still using Python version 3.7.2. Any solutions? By the way, this is the tutorial I am following: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/17/install-opencv-4-on-macos/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your python path to see where your python executable is being stored---`which python` in terminal. I bet it's still pointing to your 3.7.2 directory's python.

Comment: Also, check what `type python` -- that'll show if there's an alias or function overriding the normal `PATH` search.

Answer (score 0):

If you are switching between python versions, virtualenv can be used to initialize isolated environment with a specific python version.

> virtualenv -p [preferred-python-version] open_cv_project_env